# Downsample a 1D numpy array

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, signal-processing, resampling

I have a 1-d numpy array which I would like to downsample. Any of the following methods are acceptable if the downsampling raster doesn't perfectly fit the data:

- overlap downsample intervals
- convert whatever number of values remains at the end to a separate downsampled value
- interpolate to fit raster

basically if I have

```
1 2 6 2 1
```

and I am downsampling by a factor of 3, all of the following are ok:

```
3 3

3 1.5
```

or whatever an interpolation would give me here.

I'm just looking for the fastest/easiest way to do this.

I found [`scipy.signal.decimate`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.decimate.html), but that sounds like it *decimates* the values (takes them out as needed and only leaves one in X).  [`scipy.signal.resample`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) seems to have the right name, but I do not understand where they are going with the whole fourier thing in the description. My signal is not particularly periodic.

Could you give me a hand here? This seems like a really simple task to do, but all these functions are quite intricate...

Comment: how would you recommend I do *it*?

Comment: I would just use [`scipy.ndimage.zoom`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.ndimage.interpolation.zoom.html).  I'm sure it won't run as fast as @shx2's neighborhood mean, though, but it is more readable and easier to use if the shapes don't align perfectly.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

In the simple case where your array's size is divisible by the downsampling factor (`R`), you can `reshape` your array, and take the mean along the new axis:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.array([1.,2,6,2,1,7])
R = 3
a.reshape(-1, R)
=> array([[ 1.,  2.,  6.],
         [ 2.,  1.,  7.]])

a.reshape(-1, R).mean(axis=1)
=> array([ 3.        ,  3.33333333])
```

In the general case, you can pad your array with `NaN`s to a size divisible by `R`, and take the mean using `scipy.nanmean`.

```
import math, scipy
b = np.append(a, [ 4 ])
b.shape
=> (7,)
pad_size = math.ceil(float(b.size)/R)*R - b.size
b_padded = np.append(b, np.zeros(pad_size)*np.NaN)
b_padded.shape
=> (9,)
scipy.nanmean(b_padded.reshape(-1,R), axis=1)
=> array([ 3.        ,  3.33333333,  4.])
```

Comment: `nanmean` is [available in NumPy](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.nanmean.html) since version 1.8.0.

Answer (score 3):

Here are a few approaches using either linear interpolation or the Fourier method. These methods support upsampling as well as downsampling.

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import resample
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def ResampleLinear1D(original, targetLen):
    original = np.array(original, dtype=np.float)
    index_arr = np.linspace(0, len(original)-1, num=targetLen, dtype=np.float)
    index_floor = np.array(index_arr, dtype=np.int) #Round down
    index_ceil = index_floor + 1
    index_rem = index_arr - index_floor #Remain

    val1 = original[index_floor]
    val2 = original[index_ceil % len(original)]
    interp = val1 * (1.0-index_rem) + val2 * index_rem
    assert(len(interp) == targetLen)
    return interp

if __name__=="__main__":

    original = np.sin(np.arange(256)/10.0)
    targetLen = 100

    # Method 1: Use scipy interp1d (linear interpolation)
    # This is the simplest conceptually as it just uses linear interpolation. Scipy
    # also offers a range of other interpolation methods.
    f = interp1d(np.arange(256), original, 'linear')
    plt.plot(np.apply_along_axis(f, 0, np.linspace(0, 255, num=targetLen)))

    # Method 2: Use numpy to do linear interpolation
    # If you don't have scipy, you can do it in numpy with the above function
    plt.plot(ResampleLinear1D(original, targetLen))

    # Method 3: Use scipy's resample
    # Converts the signal to frequency space (Fourier method), then back. This
    # works efficiently on periodic functions but poorly on non-periodic functions.
    plt.plot(resample(original, targetLen))

    plt.show()
```

Comment: Perhaps your answer would get a better audience over at this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50301330/downsampling-signal-from-100-21-hz-to-8-hz-non-integer-decimation-factor.  They are still missing an answer.

Answer (score 0):

If array size is not divisible by downsampling factor (R), reshaping (splitting) of array can be done using np.linspace followed by mean of each subarray.

```
input_arr = np.arange(531)

R = 150 (number of split)

split_arr = np.linspace(0, len(input_arr), num=R+1, dtype=int)

dwnsmpl_subarr = np.split(input_arr, split_arr[1:])

dwnsmpl_arr = np.array( list( np.mean(item) for item in dwnsmpl_subarr[:-1] ) )
```

Comment: Generally, answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the 
code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.