# Downsampling signal from 100.21 Hz to 8 Hz (non-integer decimation factor)

Tags: python, pandas, interpolation, downsampling

I have found the following method to downsample a signal in python. I would like to use this method with a `sample_rate` of 100.21 but I think currently it only works for integer powers of two. Is there a possibility to downsample my signal with frequency 100.21 Hz to 8 Hz?

```
def interpolateDataTo8Hz(data,sample_rate,startTime):
    # Downsample
    idx_range = range(0,len(data))
    data = data.iloc[idx_range[0::int(sample_rate)/8]]

    # Set the index to be 8Hz
    data.index = pd.DatetimeIndex(start=startTime,periods = len(data),freq='125L')

    # Interpolate all empty values
    data = interpolateEmptyValues(data)
    return data

def interpolateEmptyValues(data):
    cols = data.columns.values
    for c in cols:
        data[c] = data[c].interpolate()

    return data
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Downsample a 1D numpy array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20322079/downsample-a-1d-numpy-array)

Comment: do want to avoid alising? if so, you need a sub 4 Hz filter before decimating, then "rational fraction" resampling can achieve the decimation correctly