# How do I downsample a 1d numpy array?

Tags: python, numpy, downsampling

This seems like a very straight forward problem but I can't figure out a solution. Suppose I have a sine function `y` with 8000 samples:

```
import numpy as np

Fs = 8000
f = 1
npts = 8000
x = np.arange(npts)
y = np.sin(2 * np.pi * f * x / Fs)
```

I want to downsample this function to 6000 samples, so I tried the method of [this answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20322495/5503831)...

```
import math
from scipy import nanmean

#number of samples I want to downsample to
npts2 = 6000

#calculating the number of NaN values to pad to the array
n = math.ceil(float(y.size)/npts2)
pad_size = n*npts2 - len(y)
padded = np.append(y, np.zeros(int(pad_size))*np.NaN)

#downsampling the reshaped padded array with nanmean
downsampled = nanmean(padded.reshape((npts2, int(n))), axis = 1)
```

This gives me an array of the correct length (6000) but the last 2000 samples (i.e. the difference between the original `npts` and `npts2`) are `NaN`, and the function itself only occupies the first 4000 samples.

Is there a better way I can make this sine function 6000 samples in length?  Thanks!

**Edit**

Thanks for the replies - I realize now I was attacking this the wrong way. I decided to use the `scipy.interpolate.interp1d` function on the `y` function, and then pass it an `np.linspace` array generated with the desired number of points to interpolate to. This gives me the correctly scaled output.

```
from scipy.interpolate import interp1d

def downsample(array, npts):
    interpolated = interp1d(np.arange(len(array)), array, axis = 0, fill_value = 'extrapolate')
    downsampled = interpolated(np.linspace(0, len(array), npts))
    return downsampled

downsampled_y = downsample(y, 6000)
```

Comment: It depends *how* you want to downsample. There's a lot of different kernels and strategies to choose from.

Comment: Do you understand what your code does?  It divides the 8000 points into 4000 groups of 2, and takes their mean.  The result is 4000 new points.  Getting 6000 values requires some sort of interpolation, something more complex than this simple pairwise mean.

Answer (score 10):

Your initial sample rate of 8000 is not divisible by 6000, so this cannot be simply downsampled like the referenced post. In your scenario, scipy's [resample](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.signal.resample.html) should work.

```
from scipy import signal
downsampled =  signal.resample(y, 6000)
```

Comment: What if one wants to keep either the first or the last (or both) point of the initial signal?

Comment: you can resample everything but those two:

```downsampled =  [y[0]]  + signal.resample(y[1:-1], 6000-2) + [y[-1]]```